# How to manual re-partition OS X drive to install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard

There are 2 500GB hard drives. Can I only install Windows 7 on the startup disk? Or can I make the other one 'Master Boot Record'? What format should be chosen?

Comment: Why not boot camp?